# Facebook feed post with action link using Graph API and jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a feed post with the action link property via a POST request using the Graph API and jQuery.  The post works fine without the action link property but doesn't work when I include the action link.  The same action link property code works fine when used with the JS SDK but I want to use it directly with the Graph API. Is the action link property just not available using the Graph API (and only through the JS SDK) or am I doing something wrong?

```
var graphApiLink = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+ facebookId +'/feed';
$.post(graphApiLink,{access_token: accessToken, actions: [{'name': 'Action', 'link': 'http://www.example.com'}]},function(resp) {
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to review the information here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/#graphapicall

Keep in mind, according to FB's error messages, the post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL.

Comment: My code example uses www.example.com but actual link goes to canvas URL and works in JS SDK